# Convert levels of factor to NA based on count

Tags: r

I have a df with a variable with 82 levels. Some of these levels are only used by 1-5 observations, and I would like to set them to NA.

```
>table(df$var)
   1    2    3    4
   2    4  152  264
```

the way i would normally do this is

```
df$var[df$var=="1" | df$var=="2"] <-NA
```

but there are many levels that I need to set to NA, and I would like to simplify/automate this process.

Comment: See the `%in%` function.  Something like `df$var %in% "list of levels"` should work.

Comment: seemingly so! used `make_na <- names( table(df$var)[table(df$var) <= 5] )` and then `df$var[df$var %in% make_na] <-NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select which levels to exclude with

```
to_exclude <- names(table(df$var)[table(df$var) < 6])
```

where 6 is frequency threshold.
(`table()` returns named vector of frequencies, so we need to extract names from it with conditional sub-setting based on freq value).
And then remove all this values with NA

```
df$var[df$var %in% to_exclude] <- NA
```